# Exclude a path from Textmate2's 'command T'

Tags: textmate, textmate2

When pressing command+T (⌘T) to bring up the quick file browser, is there a way (using `.tm_properties`) to exclude a path from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a [list of the settings](http://wiki.macromates.com/Reference/Settings) on the wiki. The settings you want are `excludeInFileChooser` & `includeInFileChooser`.

Note that in r9309 it was changed so that the file must be matched by the include rule to be included.

**Addendum**: The file chooser and find window both have editable globs in their windows that default to including everything so the note about file having to be matched by an include rule isn't as relevant as it is for the sidebar or generic rules. (The glob in the window is treated as the last include rule applied.)

Answer (score 0):

The wiki page has so-so documentation of this, as well as the syntax for the work is less than ideal when dealing with paths. Here are some snippets, with comments, as to what they are accomplishing.

Maybe this will help

```
# Exclude image files
exclude = "{$exclude,*.tiff,*.png,*.jpg,*.jpeg}"

# Project should use master as the parent dir
[ "/Volumes/broux/working/{/,**}*"]
projectDirectory        = "/Volumes/broux/working/master"
```